# How to Process Row Pairs Preserving an ID Column without Dictionaries using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm searching for a better solution to a data processing problem I've encountered in my research. I have a Pandas DataFrame and I'm trying to extract all values of a particular column (Z) within a group (Frame), preserving the ID pairs given by a different column (Name). The final result doesn't have to be a Pandas object anymore but it would be nice to do this entirely in Pandas. The task is clearest with an example.

```
d=[['7500', '3.2900', '0', 'apple'],['7500', '-0.3500', '1', 'orange'],['7500', '-4.1400', '2', 'orange'],['7501', '3.4625', '0', 'apple'],['7501', '-0.2275', '1', 'apple'],['7501', '-4.1175', '2', 'orange'],['7502', '3.2087', '0', 'orange'],['7502', '-0.7313', '1', 'apple'],['7502', '-4.7513', '2', 'apple']]
df=pd.DataFrame(d, columns=["Frame","Z","Order","Name"])


>>> df
    Frame       Z   Order   Name
0   7500     3.2900 0   apple
1   7500    -0.3500 1   orange
2   7500    -4.1400 2   orange
3   7501     3.4625 0   apple
4   7501    -0.2275 1   apple
5   7501    -4.1175 2   orange
6   7502     3.2087 0   orange
7   7502    -0.7313 1   apple
8   7502    -4.7513 2   apple
```

So for each Frame group, I'd like to take the unique combinations based on the "Order" column, so for Frame 7500 group that would be:

```
(0,1)
(0,2)
(1,2)
```

But note that the number of rows in each group can vary between 1 to 5, not just 0, 1, 2. Then I'd keep track of the "Name" value of those pairs,

```
(apple, orange)
(apple, orange)
(orange, orange)
```

Then I'd pull out the "Z" values of those respective pairs, as such:

```
( 3.2900, -0.3500)
( 3.2900, -4.1400)
(-0.3500, -4.1400)
```

And now in the end, combining that data, I want two lists for each unique pair based on the Name column. We'll call those lists first_vals and second_vals for this example, but that's entirely arbitrary,

```
(apple, orange)
first_vals = [3.2900, 3.2900, ...]
second_vals = [-0.3500, -4.1400, ...]

(orange, orange)
first_vals = [-0.3500, ...]
second_vals = [-4.140, ...]
```

Here's one solution I came up with using dictionaries. It works, but I think its pretty ugly and it hides structure of the data in the dictionary key. This example relies on the group being pre-sorted by the Order column, but there's no problem with that really.

```
from itertools import combinations
from collections import defaultdict

zpairs = defaultdict(list)

for name, group in df.groupby(["Frame"]):
    order_pairs = combinations(range(len(group)), 2)
    zvals = group["Z"].values
    rowids = group["Name"].values
    for pair in order_pairs:
        pair_str = str(rowids[pair[0]])+"-"+str(rowids[pair[1]])
        zpairs[pair_str+"-first"].append(zvals[pair[0]])
        zpairs[pair_str+"-second"].append(zvals[pair[1]])
```

The result of that code looks like this:

```
>>> dict(zpairs)

{'apple-apple-first': ['3.4625', '-0.7313'],
'apple-apple-second': ['-0.2275', '-4.7513'],
'apple-orange-first': ['3.2900', '3.2900', '3.4625', '-0.2275'],
'apple-orange-second': ['-0.3500', '-4.1400', '-4.1175', '-4.1175'],
'orange-apple-first': ['3.2087', '3.2087'],
'orange-apple-second': ['-0.7313', '-4.7513'],
'orange-orange-first': ['-0.3500'],
'orange-orange-second': ['-4.1400']}
```

Is there a way to process my dataframe that doesn't rely on dictionaries and doesn't use the dictionary key to store data? This isn't really about improving performance, but that would be helpful.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve by avoiding using the dictionaries? What do you mean by "hides structure of the data in the dictionary key"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pandas approach that's accomplished in two steps:

1. Get the pairs of names and Z values for each Frame group.
2. Combine the Z value components for each pair of names.

**Step 1**

To get the pairs of names and z values, I'm going to write a helper function `get_group_pairs` that I'll call when I perform the `groupby`.  I'm doing a similar process to what you're doing in your loop, but returning the output in a `DataFrame`:

```
def get_group_pairs(grp):
    pairs = combinations(grp.index, 2)
    data = [grp.loc[p, ('Name', 'Z')].values.flatten('F') for p in pairs]
    return pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name1', 'Name2', 'Z1', 'Z2'])

namepairs = df.groupby('Frame').apply(get_group_pairs).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```

The `reset_index` is done purely to remove an unnecessary index level so the intermediate output looks nice.  It isn't necessary if you don't care about the intermediate output.  The intermediate output `namepairs`:

```
        Name1   Name2       Z1       Z2
Frame                                  
7500    apple  orange   3.2900  -0.3500
7500    apple  orange   3.2900  -4.1400
7500   orange  orange  -0.3500  -4.1400
7501    apple   apple   3.4625  -0.2275
7501    apple  orange   3.4625  -4.1175
7501    apple  orange  -0.2275  -4.1175
7502   orange   apple   3.2087  -0.7313
7502   orange   apple   3.2087  -4.7513
7502    apple   apple  -0.7313  -4.7513
```

**Step 2**

Same helper function/`groupby`/`apply` pattern as in Step 1.  Essentially, I just group using both names, and then convert the two Z columns to lists:

```
def merge_zpairs(grp):
    data = {'Z1': grp['Z1'].tolist(), 'Z2': grp['Z2'].tolist()}
    return pd.Series(data)

zpairs = namepairs.groupby(['Name1', 'Name2']).apply(merge_zpairs).reset_index()
```

Again, the `reset_index` isn't strictly necessary.  Without it you'd get a `MultiIndex` comprised of the pairs of names.  This yields the final output `zpairs`:

```
    Name1   Name2                                 Z1                                    Z2
0   apple   apple                  [3.4625, -0.7313]                    [-0.2275, -4.7513]
1   apple  orange  [3.2900, 3.2900, 3.4625, -0.2275]  [-0.3500, -4.1400, -4.1175, -4.1175]
2  orange   apple                   [3.2087, 3.2087]                    [-0.7313, -4.7513]
3  orange  orange                          [-0.3500]                             [-4.1400]
```

**Combined Code**

For convenience, here's the code from Steps 1 and 2 combined:

```
def get_group_pairs(grp):
    pairs = combinations(grp.index, 2)
    data = [grp.loc[p, ('Name', 'Z')].values.flatten('F') for p in pairs]
    return pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name1', 'Name2', 'Z1', 'Z2'])

def merge_zpairs(grp):
    data = {'Z1': grp['Z1'].tolist(), 'Z2': grp['Z2'].tolist()}
    return pd.Series(data)

namepairs = df.groupby('Frame').apply(get_group_pairs).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
zpairs = namepairs.groupby(['Name1', 'Name2']).apply(merge_zpairs).reset_index()
```

**Getting a Dictionary**

You can get a similar dictionary structure to yours, although not identical, with some minor modifications to the Step 2 code.  Essentially, instead of using `reset_index` use `to_dict` with `orient='index'`:

```
zpairs = namepairs.groupby(['Name1', 'Name2']).apply(merge_zpairs)
zpairs_dict = zpairs.to_dict(orient='index')
```

This results in a dictionary of dictionaries: the first key being the pair of names, the second key being the Z value you want.  For example, the syntax for your `'apple-apple-first'`would be:

```
zpairs_dict[('apple', 'apple')]['Z1']
```

Comment: This answer was exactly what I was looking for. The "get_group_pairs" function is very cool, thank you! However, I know I said performance wasn't a major factor, but for my large dataframe it looks like the dictionary method is about 10x faster. I guess the apply/intermediate list construction really hurts this approach. Very educational though!